# Setup Project in MonoDevelop WinForm

Tags: xamarin

I want to know how can I add a setup project in MonoDevelop, (my OS is Windows not Linux),
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sorry your question didn't get noticed any sooner. Yes, it's quite easy to set up a project in MD. All you have to do is go to the "File" menu, and select "New", under "C#" select "GTK# 2.0 project" (or whatever number you have there ... I don't know which version you are using). Then MD wants to know what name you will give your project ... so type something there, and you also can indicate which directory you want to save it in, and if you want a separate directory for your new solution. Then the fun begins. You might want to try your hand at a tutorial or so such as [this](http://monodevelop.com/stetic_gui_designer). Keep asking your questions, and keep looking around for tutorials and I think you will enjoy the ride!

Cheers